# AVAudioPlayer not playing sounds only on iPhone 4S

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, audio

I have an app on the store since one year, and few persons owning an iPhone 4S tell me that sounds are not playing on their devices. (they do not hear anything, either with earphones or with internal speaker)

I have still tested on real devices (iPhone 3G, 3GS, 4, ipod 1G, 2G, 3G, 4G, ipad 1,2,3) and all seems correct. Sounds are playing.
(tested on various OS : iOS 3.1.2 --> 6.0, and it works also in simulator)

Unfortunately i have not myself an iphone 4S for testing, so it's very hard to know what's wrong with this particular device.

Could it be a problem with iPhone sound settings ?

But maybe it's a problem regarding my code ?
So, here is the code i use to play sounds.

Is it correct ?

in the .h ...:

```
@private AVAudioPlayer* myPlayer;
```

in the .m ...:

```
-(IBAction)playMySound{
playerPlay = YES; // it's a bool variable used at an other place in the code
NSString *path;
if((path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  
       pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", idsound ] 
       ofType:@"m4a" 
       inDirectory:@"sounds"]))
    {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSError *error;
    myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    if (myPlayer == nil) {[myPlayer release]; return;}
    myPlayer.delegate = self;
    [myPlayer play];
    }
else return; 
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is really weird:

Here you correctly create the player:

```
myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
```

The you check if it is `nil`, still correct.

```
if (myPlayer == nil)
```

But then you call `release` on a nil object, which wil do nothing since the object is nil:

```
{[myPlayer release]; return;}
```

This should be a bit better:

```
NSError *error = nil;
myPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
if (myPlayer == nil) {
   NSLog(@"Error creating AVAudioPlayer: %@", error); 
   return;
}
myPlayer.delegate = self;
[myPlayer prepareToPlay];
[myPlayer play];
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your advice ! Please excuse the little error i made when copy the code : the right code was "myPlayer.delegate = self", and not "myPlayer = self", of course ! I will try with your other advice.

Comment: The `prepareToPlay` might do the trick. I've used code like this in two of my apps and I'm using an iPhone 4S without problems.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice : i have added "preparetoplay" in my code, and it works fine. Also, i have changed "[myPlayer release]; return;" with your code. it's better, of course !

Comment: Hello again, rckoenes... I was thinking I could give you a free code for the real app on the store, then you could install it for free on your iphone 4S and test if it's playing sound or not. (it's in french, but playing sound is obvious) If you agree, just visit my personal site and contact me by mail with the link at the bottom of the page. (i hope this is not infringing any rules on stackoverflow...)